# The iscroll doesn't work automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, iscroll

I am trying to scroll div in ipad. I use iscroll. Like this:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate",function(event){
     var myScroll = new IScroll('#devicesContent',  {
         click:true
     });
});
```

But what I see is strange: it doesn't work automatically. If I open it on landscape it doesn't scroll. If I change the orientation and then it scrolls, or if I open it on portrait and I need to change orientation for landscape and then it scrolls. What am I missing?

Comment: Does the `pagecreate` event itself fire?

Comment: Yes. It fire. i've tryed it on different events. I get the same result

Comment: Then you might need to show us a full example.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function(event){
    var myScroll = new IScroll('#devicesContent', { 
        eventPassthrough: true, // add this
        click:true,
        scrollX: true, 
        scrollY: false
    });
});
```

Comment: No. It doesn't help. If i set eventPassthrough: true it doesn't work on both portrait and landscape

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue is with your pagecreate event. Try "pageshow" instead.